ScyllaDB: Replication factor is 3 but requires 4 for quorum
I have a scyla db with 3 nodes.
Replication in my keyspace is the following.
{'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '3', 'datacenter2': '3'}
but in 2 of the nodes I'm getting this error :
Could not retrieve CDC streams with timestamp 2024/01/26 13:51:25 upon gossip event. Reason: "Cannot achieve consistency level for cl QUORUM. Requires 4, alive 3". Action: continuin>
why does it require 4 ??
is it needed to be configured in other place  ?

A QUORUM is a majority of the replicas in a cluster. You have 3+3=6 replicas. The majority is 4.
The warning in question should be fine if it occurs only after you restart a node. Sometimes gossip may race with CDC announcements. CDC announcements happen during specific intervals and are carried out with QUORUM consistency to ensure the majority of nodes in the cluster agree with the latest generation.
If it is sporadic, just ignore it. If it is something that is showing up on logs frequently, then it seems to imply that some nodes in the cluster have a different view of your existing cluster topology and needs to be fixed.
